# How to verify ABI matches the source code?

Tags: solidity, abi

I want to analyze the Solidity version of the source code of the smart contract of a crypto coin.

I can get the ABI from Etherscan and I can get the smart contract from, say, Github. (Assume the author is willing to share the repository link with me.)

Now, I need to audit the source code on Github to make sure it's the same source code that generated the ABI on Etherscan.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I am seeking, ideally, some free tool on the internet.

Comment: If there is ABI on etherscan for a contract, means the contract is verified, and there should be also the source codes. If you have the source code, you just need the bytecode of the contract and compare it with the compiled bytecode from sources.

Answer (score 1):

You can Verify it by

1. Comparing the full metadata of deployed Smart Contract and the Smart Contract you have
2. Basically Comaparing the ABIs of deployed Smart Contract and the Smart Contract you have